# Assert if text within an element contains specific partial text

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have an element within  tag that has release notes. I have to validate if it contains specific text. I am able to extract the text using following code:

`WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ManageSoftware.release_notes_xpath))).get_attribute("innerHTML")`

How do I assert if it contain a specific text, say "abc". Is there any function like contains() or isPresent() that I can use here?

The code that I am working on is:

```
<div id="dialog" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="width: auto; min-height: 0px; max-height: none; height: 483px;">
<pre> 
Text is here.
</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, but i don't know if its possible without using the xpath functions in selenium. The following would find a pre that contains "Text is here.":  `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//pre[contains(., 'Text is here.')]")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To validate the presence of the desired text within any element you need to use a `try-catch{}` block inducing *WebDriverWait* for `text_to_be_present_in_element()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  try:
      WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.ui-dialog-content.ui-widget-content#dialog>pre"), "Text is here"))
      print("Desired text was present")
  except TimeoutException:
      print("Desired text was not present")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  try:
      WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content' and @id='dialog']/pre"), "Text is here"))
      print("Desired text was present")
  except TimeoutException:
      print("Desired text was not present")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It worked for me. The only thing is the release notes that I am validating is too long and if I validate for a failure of test with a wrong keyword that does not exist then it throws timeout exception. And I am not sure if there are ways to speed up the search process to give a failure. Also just to confirm the solution that you gave is checking if the expected text is contained in the release notes? that is validate partial text match?

Comment: @nd23 You can always replace the string `Text is here` with a variable containing a smaller/larger text.

Comment: Sorry I didn't quite understand this comment.
In my solution I am using this:
```element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.ui-dialog-content.ui-widget-content#dialog>pre"), "Text"))```

to validate that it is contained within "Text is here". What I meant was if I check for a test failure it takes too long is there a way to make the search faster?

Comment: @nd23 Checkout the updated answer and let me know if you have further queries.

Comment: Thank you. This is not exactly what I though could be alternate solution in selenium but I can use this to get rid of timeout exception.